# Prove that a positive monic polynomial with even degree has a minima but not a maxima.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, nonstandard-analysis, extreme-value-theorem

> Prove that a positive monic polynomial with even degree has a minima but not a maxima. You may use the fact that there are finitely many critical points.

---

Let's take the worst case where the first derivative has a single zero.

Let the polynomial be $f(x)$

We know $f'(c) = 0$ because $f'(x)$ is a odd degree polynomial.

Therefore we have a interior critical point.

Also by $\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x)= + \infty$ we get no maxima.

Therefore $c$ is either minima or nothing.

Out of first/second derivative and direct test, I don't know what to apply here.

I thought about EVT but I don't know $[a,b]$ here.

What should I do now ?

Comment: I have suppressed the tag "non-standard analysis" which has nothing to do here (theory of infinitesimals)

Comment: It seems tout should exclude the case of the polynomial $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is even degree, as you pointed out one has $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=\infty$ in addition to $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$.  Now choose $a$ small enough and $b$ big enough so that so that $f(a)>f(c)$ and $f(b)>f(c)$ where $c$ is the point you found.  Then apply the extreme value theorem on the interval $[a,b]$ to get a local minimum.

If in addition one wants to find a global minimum, choose $a,b$ so that $f$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,a)$ and increasing on $(b,\infty)$.

Comment: By EVT we can say that $f$ has a maxima at either $a$ or $b$ and minima at $c$ because it is the only other critical point. Am I correct ?

Comment: No, I meant to apply EVT to get a *minimum*. I notice that my answer is not completely precise so I will correct it now.

Comment: I don't get it completely, EVT say that a continuous function in a closed interval has a minimum and a maximum. We have 3 critical points $a,b,c$ because $a,b$ are endpoints of the interval and $c$ is where first derivative is zero. By critical point theorem we can say the minimum and maximum is at $a,b,c$ and no where else in the interval $[a,b]$. Since $f(a), f(b) > f(c)$ therefore minima can't be at $a,b$ thus it has to at $c$.

Comment: Is this correct ? I don't get "apply EVT to get a minimum", do I neeed to find value of minima ?

Comment: I will clarify in my *answer*.

Comment: Note that the point $c$ you found satisfies $f'(c)=0$ but it may not be a local minimum (it might be an inflection point).

Comment: Ok I think I got it this time. Since $f$ is increasing on $(b, \infty)$ and decreasing on $(-\infty, a)$ then one of two things may happen. First that $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$ or $f$ decreases then increases on $[a,b]$. We divide $[a,b]$ in infinite partitions $a, a+ \delta,  \ ... \ , a+ H\delta = b$. Let $a+ K\delta$ be the last point where $f$ is decreasing and let $\displaystyle d := {a + K\delta + a + (K+1)\delta \over 2}$ , therefore we get $f(x) > f(a + K\delta) > f(d)$ where $x <  a +K\delta$ and $f(d) \le f(a + (K+1)\delta) \lt f(x)$, where $f(x) > a + K\delta$. From this we get ...

Comment: $f(\alpha) > f(d) < f(\beta)$ where $\alpha < d$ and $\beta > d$. Hence $d$ is minimum ? But I did not use EVT here ?

Comment: @A---B I am absolutely delighted that you seek to use infinitesimals wherever possible but in this case why not simply apply the extreme value theorem? I do believe that the infinite partition approach is the best way of proving the extreme value theorem; see [these lecture notes](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/tidg.pdf).

Comment: Yes I refer to them when needed.  Thank you for the compliement and all the help.

Comment: @MikhailKatz When proving EVT, partitioning a compact $K$ into infinitesimal width pieces is the most straightforward approach in Internal Set Theory. However, there is also a more general approach. In IST any set has a finite subset containing its standard elements. If $F$ is the finite subset of the compact set $K$, you prove EVT by letting $a\in F$ be the point at which the finite set $f|_F$ has a maximum and then prove that $\mathrm{st}(a)$ is the point at which $f|_K$ has a maximum given $f$ continuous and $K$ compact. Do you know of a hyperreal analog to this?

Comment: @MikhailKatz The above proof generalizes better outside of strictly $\mathbb{R}$ (and, moreover, the above technique can be used repeatedly instead of more specific constructions such as intervals). I can elaborate the IST proof, but it might be better to do so in a question. I'm interested if you can also do this sort of thing with hyperreals.

Comment: @GPhys, don't get me wrong I am all in favor of IST; see e.g., [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00425). I think it is a more natural foundation for modern mathematics than ZFC.  However for beginners it can be hard to make join the dots. I feel that for beginners it is easier pass via the hyperreals on the way to IST. As far as your mathematical question is concerned, certainly there is a hyperreal version of this; one just needs a model that has enough saturation to be able to prove that there is a hyperfinite set containing every point in the compact.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $a = f(0)$. Since $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} = \infty$, there exists $M > 0$ such that
$$\vert x \vert > M \implies \vert f(x) \vert > a.$$
Now apply the extreme value theorem.

Comment: Why we need $M$ ?

Answer (score 1):

For both large positive and large negative values the leading term dominates (and turns the polynomial positive). Thus it has no maximum. But then it also must have a minimum because the polynomial cannot be unbounded over a small interval (lest it have an asymptote, which polynomials don't).

Comment: Why can't I say this for odd polynomials ? they also don't have asymptotes.

Comment: @A---B Odd polynomials don't go to infinity for large positive and negative values. They go to -infinity and infinity.